# How could I get the new ID of an inserted record in ASP.NET DetailsView using LinqDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, detailsview

I've got the answer if I were using SqlDataSource by Overriding the Insert Statement and use the @@IDENTITY property, but when I use the LinqDataSource, I couldn't override the Insert statement!

so, the problem is:

I'm using ASP.NET Webform, DetailsViewControl in Insert Mode and LinqDataSource.

I want to retrieve the new ID of the inserted record. What's the easiest and the most efficient way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [LinqDataSource.Inserted Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.inserted.aspx)

Example from MSDN shows that newProduct.ProductID is the new ID.

```
protected void LinqDataSource_Inserted(object sender, LinqDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception == null)
    {
        Product newProduct = (Product)e.Result;

        // newProduct.ProductID is the new ID
    }
    else
    {
        // Some Exception - e.Exception.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to fire a new query to get the new ID, I want to override the INSERT statement or use another magic tool!

Comment: It is not firing the new query. This event is fired after the insert statement on the datasource is executed.

Comment: aha, seems great! Thanks @amit_g